# std::filebuf passed to std::ifstream not always called

Tags: c++, linux, fstream, file-pointer, filebuf

### The Goal

Have **unbuffered I/O** and **disabled kernel page cache** for a legacy C++11 program. This feature must be **on demand** (through an executable parameter). The idea is to reduce the memory overhead of I/O operations regardless of performances. I am not sure this is the right way to achieve this though...

### My attempt

The code base being quite big, with massive usage of `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` spread accross different binaries/libraries, my goal is to implement a class deriving from `std::filebuf` that relies on C I/O features (`FILE *`, `open()` so I can pass `O_DIRECT` flag, etc..), and pass it to a `std::ifstream` object (only inputs for the moment) using the inherited method `std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>* std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::rdbuf(std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>*)`.

### The issue

The issue is that the `std::ifstream` object seems to have in fact two internal buffers. See the code to understand my experiment (there might still be some obvious mistakes).

**My filebuf**

```cpp
// FileBuf.h
class FileBuf : public std::filebuf {
public:
    FileBuf();
    virtual ~FileBuf();
    virtual std::filebuf* open(const char* filename,  std::ios_base::openmode mode);
    virtual std::filebuf* open(const std::string filename, std::ios_base::openmode mode);
    virtual bool is_open() const;
    virtual std::filebuf* close();
    virtual std::streambuf* setbuf(char_type* s, std::streamsize n);
    virtual int_type overflow(int c = traits_type::eof());
    virtual FileBuf::int_type underflow();
    virtual int sync();
private:
    int _fd;
    FILE * _fp;
    char _buff[1]; // minimal size
};
```

```cpp
// FileBuf.cpp
FileBuf::FileBuf()
: std::filebuf(), _fd(0), _fp(NULL)
{}

FileBuf::~FileBuf() {
  close(); // RAII
}

std::filebuf* FileBuf::open(const char* filename,  std::ios_base::openmode mode) {
  std::cout << "open(const char*, ..): filename=" << filename << ", mode=" << mode << std::endl;
  // not finished, need to handle all modes
  int flags = O_RDONLY;
  mode_t fmode = S_IRUSR;
  std::string smode = "r";
  _fd = ::open(filename, flags, fmode);
  _fp = ::fdopen(_fd, smode.c_str());
  return _fp != NULL ? this : nullptr;
}

std::filebuf* FileBuf::open(const std::string filename, std::ios_base::openmode mode) {
  std::cout << "open(const std::string, ..): filename=" << filename << ", mode=" << mode << std::endl;
  return open(filename.c_str(), mode);
}

std::streambuf* FileBuf::setbuf(char_type* s, std::streamsize n) {
  return this;
}

bool FileBuf::is_open() const {
  return (_fp != NULL);
}

std::filebuf* FileBuf::close() {
  std::cout << "close()" << std::endl;
  if (_fp) {
    if (std::fclose(_fp) == 0) {
      return this;
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}

FileBuf::int_type FileBuf::overflow(int_type c) {
  std::cout << "overflow()" << std::endl;
  if (traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof())) {
    return (sync() == 0) ? traits_type::not_eof(c) : traits_type::eof();
  } else {
    return ((std::fputc(c, _fp) != EOF) ? traits_type::not_eof(c) : traits_type::eof());
  }
}

FileBuf::int_type FileBuf::underflow()
{
  std::cout << "underflow(): _fp=" << _fp << std::endl;
  if (gptr() == NULL || gptr() >= egptr()) {
    int gotted = fgetc(_fp);
    if (gotted == EOF) {
      return traits_type::eof();
    } else {
      *_buff = gotted;
      setg(_buff, _buff, _buff + 1);
      return traits_type::to_int_type(*_buff);
    }
  } else {
    return traits_type::to_int_type(*_buff);
  }
}

int FileBuf::sync()
{
  std::cout << "sync()" << std::endl;
  return (std::fflush(_fp) == 0) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

**Client code**

```cpp
std::string buff(1024, '\0');
std::ifstream ifs;
FileBuf fileBuf;

ifs.std::istream::rdbuf(&fileBuf); // file buf passed here

std::cout << "rdbuf()=" << static_cast<void*>(ifs.rdbuf()) << ", istream.rdbuf()=" << static_cast<void*>(ifs.std::istream::rdbuf()) << ", &fileBuf=" << static_cast<void*>(&fileBuf) << std::endl;
ifs.open("data/test1/delta");
ifs.read(&buff[0], 1024);
```

**The output**

```
rdbuf()=0x7fffffffdb10, istream.rdbuf()=0x7fffffffd9f0, &fileBuf=0x7fffffffd9f0
underflow(): _fp=0
// !! SEGFAULT !!
```

As the output shows, the two flavors of `rdbuf()` does not refer to the same internal buffer, and `FileBuf::open` is never called while it is supposed to be, as specified in [std::basic_ifstream<CharT,Traits>::open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open):

> Effectively calls rdbuf()->open(filename, mode | ios_base::in)

I understand what is happening: the internal buffer object returned by `std::basic_ifstream::rdbuf` is being called instead of the one from `std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::rdbuf`, but still, I have no clue how to get the behavior I want.

I'd like to avoid -at all costs- to replace all `std::ifstream` references with a custom implementation of it as it would imply to replace the type in all current declarations.

**NOTE:** I am compiling with **gcc** and **libstdc++**.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the motivation behind the goal? Could you make from the 3 code snippets one big code snippet, add `int main()` to the 3rd code snippet and add missing `#include`s? It is helpful when the code is easy to copy and run and test... | `at all costs- to replace all std::ifstream references with a custom implementation` But you will have to do _something_. Isn't _adding_ yet another `FileBuf` to each `std::ifstream` and then adding yet another `...rdbuf(&filebuf)` call to each constructor harder then replacing the declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ifstream` is **always** going to be using with it's own `std::filebuf`. That `std::filebuf` is *separate* to the one owned by `std::basic_ios`. Setting is has no effect, as it's never used and `std::ifstream` always uses his own. See also [Difference between "internal" vs "associated" stream buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591500/difference-between-internal-vs-associated-stream-buffer) .

What you can do instead, you can overwrite the implementation of the file input/output operations in libstdc++ with your own implementation. Take the original implementation from [libstdc++/basic_file_stdio.c](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/config/io/basic_file_stdio.cc.html#_ZNSt12__basic_fileIcE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmodei) and patch it with custom behavior. Dynamic linker will prefer your symbol over the shared one. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <bits/basic_file.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>

// code copied from  libstdc++-v3/config/io/basic_file_stdio.cc
namespace {
  // Map ios_base::openmode flags to a string for use in fopen().
  // Table of valid combinations as given in [lib.filebuf.members]/2.
  static const char*
  fopen_mode(std::ios_base::openmode mode)
  {
    enum
      {
        in     = std::ios_base::in,
        out    = std::ios_base::out,
        trunc  = std::ios_base::trunc,
        app    = std::ios_base::app,
        binary = std::ios_base::binary
      };
    // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
    // 596. 27.8.1.3 Table 112 omits "a+" and "a+b" modes.
    switch (mode & (in|out|trunc|app|binary))
      {
      case (   out                 ): return "w";
      case (   out      |app       ): return "a";
      case (             app       ): return "a";
      case (   out|trunc           ): return "w";
      case (in                     ): return "r";
      case (in|out                 ): return "r+";
      case (in|out|trunc           ): return "w+";
      case (in|out      |app       ): return "a+";
      case (in          |app       ): return "a+";
      case (   out          |binary): return "wb";
      case (   out      |app|binary): return "ab";
      case (             app|binary): return "ab";
      case (   out|trunc    |binary): return "wb";
      case (in              |binary): return "rb";
      case (in|out          |binary): return "r+b";
      case (in|out|trunc    |binary): return "w+b";
      case (in|out      |app|binary): return "a+b";
      case (in          |app|binary): return "a+b";
      default: return 0; // invalid
      }
  }
}

namespace std
{
  __basic_file<char>*
  __basic_file<char>::open(const char* __name, ios_base::openmode __mode,
                           int /*__prot*/)
  {
    __basic_file* __ret = NULL;
    const char* __c_mode = fopen_mode(__mode);
    if (__c_mode && !this->is_open())
      {
          // HERE I ADDED THIS LINE HERE I ADDED THIS LINE HERE I ADDED THIS LINE HERE I ADDED THIS LINE 
          const char *str = "TODO: set O_DIRECT here\n";
          write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, strlen(str));
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_LFS
        if ((_M_cfile = fopen64(__name, __c_mode)))
#else
        if ((_M_cfile = fopen(__name, __c_mode)))
#endif
          {
            _M_cfile_created = true;
            __ret = this;
          }
      }
    return __ret;
  }
}

int main() {
    std::string buff(1024, '\0');
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("/tmp/1.cpp");
    ifs.read(&buff[0], 1024);
}
```

The program compiled and outputs on my system (the file is opened successfully):

```
TODO: set O_DIRECT here
```

You will have to replace `fopen` with `open+fdopen` and also replace `__basic_file::close()` so it also does `close(fileno(..))`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This change implies that all open/close operations of my program will execute this? How can I make this depend on an executable parameter?

Comment: Also, I think that I don't need to provide my own close() implementation since it already does a `fclose(_M_cfile)` which will automatically invalidate the associate file descriptor obtained with `open()`

Comment: `This change implies that all open/close operations of my program will execute this?` Yes. `How can I make this depend on an executable parameter?` It's `open(const char* __name`. Compare `__name`. `which will automatically invalidate the associate file descriptor obtained with open()` Och, you right, I always thought `fdopen` does not close it.